# Tidying data : how to create a column distributing values of specific rows into groups in the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tidy

it is my first question and I would like to know a smart way of doing the following:

I have a large dataset that looks something like this:

| identifier | name | group | period | product | gross_sales | net_sales | expense |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nameone | groupone | q1 | baloons | 20000 | 10000 | 0 |
| 1 | nameone | groupone | q1 | cartoons | 2000 | 10000 | 0 |
| 1 | nameone | groupone | q2 | cartoons | 20000 | 10000 | 0 |
| 2 | nametwo | groupone | q1 | baloons | 1 | 1000 | 0 |
| 3 | namethree | grouptwo | q4 | cartoons | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | nameone | groupone | q1 | expense | 0 | -1000 | 1000 |

I would like to distribute the expense and the gross sales of each identifier that has an expense in the product column ([product == expense]) in its sales entries ([volume > 0 and (product != expense)]) using gross_sales to apportion proportionately by product. The DF would look something like this at the end:

| identifier | name | group | period | product | gross_sales | net_sales | expense |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nameone | groupone | q1 | baloons | 20000 | 9500 | 500 |
| 1 | nameone | groupone | q1 | cartoons | 20000 | 9500 | 500 |
| 1 | nameone | groupone | q2 | cartoons | 20000 | 10000 | 0 |
| 2 | nametwo | groupone | q1 | baloons | 20000 | 1000 | 0 |
| 3 | namethree | grouptwo | q4 | cartoons | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Thank you ! :D

A solution previously presented by @Andrej Kesely pointed me to:

```
## Since I have only one expense row per identifier per period or none
m = df["product"] == "expense"
expenses = df[m].groupby(["identifier, "period"])["expense"].first().agg(dict)

df["expense"] = (
    df[~m]
    .groupby(["identifier", "period"])["gross_sales"]
    .transform(lambda x: expenses.get(x.name, np.nan) / len(x))
)
```

And I got it working, but it is dividing the expense equally among the products and I need it to be proportionately.

I then tried :

```
df["expense"] = (
    df[~m]
    .groupby(["identifier", "period"])["gross_sales"]
    .transform(lambda x: expenses.get(x.name, np.nan)/ sum(x) if (sum(x) > 0) else 0)
```

And although it worked, it was not properly, the sum of all expenses did not totaled the amount pre transform.

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you have multiple rows of expenses for each identifier or is there always only 0 or 1?

Comment: Only one expense row for each identifier for each period, or none.

Comment: So, in theory, you can have another row for identifier 1, with a period of q2 and a product == expense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one `expense` or none, you can try:

```
m = df["product"] == "expense"
expenses = df[m].groupby(["name", "group"])["expense"].first().agg(dict)

df["expense"] = (
    df[~m]
    .groupby(["name", "group"])["volume"]
    .transform(lambda x: expenses.get(x.name, np.nan) / len(x))
)
print(df[~m])
```

Prints:

```
   identifier       name     group period   product  volume  net_sales  expense
0           1    nameone  groupone     q1   baloons      10      10000    500.0
1           1    nameone  groupone     q1  cartoons       1      10000    500.0
2           2    nametwo  groupone     q1   baloons       1       1000      NaN
3           3  namethree  grouptwo     q4  cartoons       0          0      NaN
```

---

EDIT: To divide expenses proportionally, you can try:

```
m = df["product"] == "expense"
expenses = df[m].groupby(["identifier", "period"])["expense"].first().agg(dict)

df["expense"] = (
    df[~m]
    .groupby(["identifier", "period"])["gross_sales"]
    .transform(
        lambda x: [(gs / x.sum()) * expenses.get(x.name, np.nan) for gs in x]
    )
)
print(df[~m])
```

Prints:

```
   identifier       name     group period   product  gross_sales  net_sales     expense
0           1    nameone  groupone     q1   baloons        20000      10000  909.090909
1           1    nameone  groupone     q1  cartoons         2000      10000   90.909091
2           1    nameone  groupone     q2  cartoons        20000      10000         NaN
3           2    nametwo  groupone     q1   baloons            1       1000         NaN
4           3  namethree  grouptwo     q4  cartoons            0          0         NaN
```

Comment: Your solution almost worked, I see where you are at but I was unable to implement , I had to do a feel adjustments because I might have the same identifier apearing in different periods but only one expense per period per identifier got stuck because of an error in x.name "'Series' object has no attribute 'name', do you know why ?

Comment: My confusion then , I thought it was referring to the "name" column , I changed the last paramenter to .name and len(x) and it worked, but it is dividing everything equally among products instead of proportionately